# Methods section and location of materials

Tags: writing

This is probably an irrelevant question but curious to know because I couldn't find answers.

What city, state, or country should one use when listing reagents or materials in the methods section? And when is it even needed? Do you use HQ?

Some companies (i.e Thermofisher) have brands under their umbrella and there's merging and changes to product brands, would you use Carlsbad for Invitrogen or Rockford, IL or Mass? How to handle the changing HQ and companies/branding?

When is it necessary to list the company, city? Antibodies I can understand, but what's the determination for what gets the company/city? It seems to be random on papers and you could list endless amounts and it'd be too much.

Thoughts?

Comment: If it is a journal paper, ask the editor. If it's theses, ask your supervisor.